ID old (black & white?) movie, two knights fight a dragon
Whenever I find myself on a nostalgia kick (like when the Charlie Brown Christmas special appears on TV), one thing that comes to mind is an old movie we were shown in grade school (about 30 years ago) in the auditorium with an old projector on a huge screen. I can only remember bits and pieces but here's a few key parts that will hopefully jog someone's memory better than mine. It featured two knights, almost of a curious Laurel & Hardy template (if I'm remembering them correctly); one "smarter" and more in-charge, yet ultimately cowardly, and the other a sort of bumbling oaf sidekick. At one point they face what I think must have been a dragon, and the sidekick is killed, while the cowardly one escapes. Later I think he is haunted by the sidekick, or suffers some manner of guilt; I can't quite remember.
I wish I could recall more but.....does that sound familiar to anyone?

Was it a silent film?

You are describing the tale "The Singing Bone", integrated into the main plot of film The Wonderful World of the Brothers Grimm (1962) based on the fanciful biography of the German fairy-tale collectors.


This collection of time honored and beloved children's stories comes
  to life with the help of special effects. The fictionalized accounts
  of the lives of Wilhelm Grimm (Lawrence Harvey) and brother Jacob
  (Karl Boehm).The brothers are requested to write the history of a
  local duke and his noble family. The imaginative brothers are probed
  to telling their own collection of fables. In "The Dancing Princess"
  the King (Jim Backus) wonders why his daughter (Yvette Mimieux) wears
  out her slippers every day. He offers his daughter's hand in marriage
  to the man who can solve the mystery. Woodsman (Russ Tamblyn) follows
  her at night to the camp of dancing gypsies, where the princess dances
  the night away. The princess and the woodsman dance together and fall
  in love, and the benevolent King gives his blessing to their impending
  marriage. In "The Cobbler And The Elves" the cobbler (Lawrence Harvey)
  falls behind in his shoe repair business when he carves wooden elves
  for needy children. One night, the elves magically come to life and
  help the kindly cobbler by completing the unfinished work he has
  neglected by helping bring happiness to the children with his original
  toys. Part three is "The Singing Bone." Ludwig (Terry-Thomas) is a
  conniving knight who takes credit for slaying a dragon. Hans (Buddy
  Hackett) is the real dragon slayer, but he is killed by Ludwig to
  silence him. One of Han's bones comes to life as a singing instrument
  and tells the truth about the dragon. Hans is brought back to life for
  his honesty, and Ludwig becomes his servant as Hans becomes a noble
  knight. In between the fables, the duke pressures the brothers Grimm
  for the finished product on his family's history. The duke fires the
  brothers, and a disheartened Wilhelm becomes sick and nearly dies. His
  fairy tale characters come to life one night to tell Wilhelm he must
  pull through so their stories can be told to children all over the
  world. This film is delightfully entertaining for children of all
  ages. rottentomatoes

The story focuses on the Grimm brothers, Wilhelm (Laurence Harvey) and
  Jacob (Karlheinz Böhm), and is biographical and fantastical at the
  same time. They are working to finish a history for a local Duke
  (Oscar Homolka), though Wilhelm is more interested in collecting fairy
  tales and often spends their money to hear them from locals. Tales
  such as "The Dancing Princess" and "The Cobbler and the Elves" are
  integrated into the main plot. One of the tales is told as an
  experiment to three children in a book store to see if publishing a
  collection of fairytales has any merit. Another tale, "The Singing
  Bone", is told by an old woman (Martita Hunt) in the forest who tells
  stories to children, while the uninvited Wilhelm secretly listens
  through an open window. The culmination of this tale involves a
  jeweled dragon and features the most involved usage of the film's
  special effects.
Wilhelm loses the manuscript of the Duke's family history while
  writing down this third story - he is supposed to be collecting
  additional information for the family history - and the brothers
  cannot meet their deadline. They are required to pay their rent, which
  was waived while they worked. As a result of wading through a stream
  in an effort to retrieve the manuscript (which fell into the water
  after his briefcase broke open), Wilhelm becomes critically ill with
  potentially fatal pneumonia. He dreams that at night various fairytale
  characters come to him, begging him to name them before he dies. In
  the dream, Russ Tamblyn reprises his role as Tom Thumb from the 1958
  film. His fever breaks and Wilhelm recovers completely, continuing his
  own work while his brother publishes regular books including a history
  of German grammar and a book on law. Jacob, shaken by his brother's
  experience, begins to collaborate on the fairy tales with Wilhelm.
They are ultimately invited to receive honorary membership at the
  Berlin Royal Academy, which makes no mention of the tales in their
  invitation. Jacob prepares to make a speech deliberately insulting the
  Academy for snubbing Wilhelm. As their train pulls into the station,
  hordes of children arrive, chanting, "We want a story!" Wilhelm
  begins, "Once upon a time, there were two brothers." The children
  cheer, and the film ends with a caption card that reads "…and they
  lived happily ever after." Wikipedia

Most amusing is the rendering of the story of "The Singing Bone," with
  Terry-Thomas and Buddy Hackett performing as the knight and his
  faithful servant who go to slay a dragon in a cave. This one has the
  advantage of its performers' elaborate comic skills and the
  spectacular quality of the jeweled dragon that does, at least, fill
  the huge screen. NYTimes




Clip 01/ Clip 02

Well I'll be damned, I think you nailed it. And sure enough Buddy Hackett perfectly fits the template I was trying to describe, I'd just forgotten all about him. I really could have sworn this was a B&W film, and maybe even a silent one, as the other commenter was inquiring. Either there was more than one version of this or I just plain remembered wrong.....probably the latter. Thanks so much for the info!
